# Finding friends with 2 common friends in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given this relationship:

(p1:PERSON)-[:FRIEND]->(p2:PERSON)

is there a way to find pairs of people eg. (p1,p2) who have 2 or more friends in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (p1:PERSON)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:PERSON)-[:FRIEND]-(p2:PERSON)
WITH p1, p2, count(friend) AS friend_count
WHERE friend_count >= 2
RETURN p1, p2, friend_count
```

But keep in mind that this will be a cartesean product of your `PERSON` nodes, so as the collection grows, the query will have to look at every combination of every pair of people.  That's fine as long as you don't care about running this query a lot / running it fast.

Also note that the common style for labels is `UpperCamelCase`.  See this for a pretty good style guide:

http://nigelsmall.com/zen

Comment: this doesnt work. I see this error: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 3, column 2 (offset: 114))

Comment: the first "return" needs to be a "with"